# Jquery .load stops returning after 2 times

Tags: jquery

I'm busy with a browser game but i have a problem.
After 2 times jquery stops returning the page.
Here's my code:

```
$('#build-1').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#bd2').load("build.php?act=chk&bid=storage&doa=bst43&space=1");
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
```

This I expect as return:

```
<script>
    setbuild();
    $('#tab1').load('tab.php?space=0');
</script>
```

The script is working for 2 times then it stops working. I see it is still be sent but not recieving anything. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you please include the PHP ... if you seeing it being sent and not returned my guess would be that the problem is within the PHP not the jQuery ... any errors in the PHP / Webserver logs ?

Comment: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8015538/gui/build.php my code it is a very messy code but its working well.. expect the build insert first 1 ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Ajax response to rebuild the clickable elements, then you need to rebind the click event function to those "new" elements

Comment: With the click element is nothing wrong.
it is just the .load or returning in php